# How can i use Google-o-Meter or Google Vizualisation API with Jenkins

Tags: google-visualization, jenkins

Here is a sample that displays a static chart:

```
  
    
    
    google.load("visualization", "1.0", {packages:["imagechart"]});
    
    
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        dataTable.addColumn('string');
        dataTable.addColumn('number');
        dataTable.addColumn('string');

        // Row data is [chl, data point, point label]
        dataTable.addRows([
        ['January',40,undefined],
        ['February',60,'Initial recall'],
        ['March',60,'Product withdrawn'],
        ['April',45,undefined],
        ['May',47,'Relaunch'],
        ['June',75,undefined],
        ['July',70,undefined],
        ['August',72,undefined]
        ]);

        var options = {cht: 'lc', chds:'0,160', annotationColumns:[{column:2, size:12, type:'flag', priority:'high'},]};

        var chart = new google.visualization.ImageChart(document.getElementById('line_div'));
        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
      }
```

How can i replace the static values and variables in  dataTable.addRows([ with real live data ?

In case the compete code is not visible, refer to :
http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/genericimagechart.html

When this Javascript is copied to the "Description" it renders a chart, what i want to know is how to replace the name/value in  dataTable.addRows, to the name/values coming from Jenkins